Hyperparameter Tuning for Multiple Time Series
I am developing a time-series model utilizing NeuralProphet for forecasting the demand of products by day. I have grouped the products into a number of clusters by features such as average demand, standard deviation in demand, and time-series length.
I believe the optimal approach for this problem would be to use Global Local Modeling to create one model for each cluster and use that model to generate individual forecasts for each product. However, I am struggling to wrap my head around how to properly tune hyperparameters for a global local model. My goal is to create a model with an acceptable degree of accuracy across all products in their respective cluster, but I am not sure how to do that without running trials on each individual item.
I have tested using Bayesian Optimization to tune hyperparameters in the context of a single time-series model and gotten great results, but it would be far too time-consuming to run dozens of trials on each individual product in the case of a multiple time-series model. I had thought about taking samples from each cluster, but then how would I choose the samples? Even if I had a list of the best hyperparameters for each product in a cluster, how would I then narrow them down to a single set for the whole cluster?
I would be very grateful for any recommendations on how to tackle this problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
